# Installing a LAMP Web Server on Amazon Linux

Tags: lamp

I am trying to follow some amazon tutorial(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) related to AWS. This will allow me to install php and mysql on a Red Hat Webserver(IAM) I just setup. I get the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ ~]$ sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package httpd24 available.
No package php56 available.
No package mysql55-server available.
No package php56-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

thanks,
Byron

Comment: This is just a guess but you said you are using a Red Hat AMI when the example is for the Amazon Linux AMI. Might need to check the repositories yum is using and see if those packages are available.

Comment: True that. I just realized that Amazon Linux AMI is the only instance where it will work, since it is an image with a pre configured tools and repositories like php, Python, Ruby, Perl, etc. I will setup another instanace with this features.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check with:
    `cat /etc/system-release` on your ec2 instance command-line
This will most-likely show that you have Amazon Linux 2 instance running instead of AMI. 
For successful execution of your command try launching EC2 instance from custom AMI as follows:

1. Open the **EC2 console**.
2. From the navigation bar on the left, choose **AMIs**
3. Find AMI you want to use to launch a new instance. These can be **Owned by me**, **Public Images** or **Private Images**. Use search bar for filtering.
4. Select AMI and then select **Launch**.
5. Choose instance type, and choose **Next: Configure Instance Details**
6. Review the **Instance Details** and then select **Review and Launch**.
7. Confirm preferred boot volume, choose **Next**.
8. Select **Launch**.
9. Create a new key pair or select an existing one.
10. Choose **Launch Instances**.
11. Choose **View Instances** to check the status of your instance.